# Java 'print *variable*'

Tags: java

So, I just took a CS test, and one of the questions, was a for loop, and after it loops, it does...

`print k;`

I don't think it is possible to 'print' a variable, using just, 'print'..
Someone tell me, if it's possible or not, because one of my teammates say it is possible.

Comment: It could have been pseudocode...

Comment: This line compiles only if `print` is a type, `k` will be a variable.

Comment: It may be Python for all we know.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Well, the question is tagged `java`, so...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I know, but again given the missing detail from the question, I think all we can say is that the question could be / should be improved upon.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: Completely agree, it can and should.

Answer (score 3):

As 0A0D said probably pseudocode, the normal way to print in java is to do a

```
System.out.print(variable);
```

Comment: This answer should be a comment

Comment: @Aubin: I disagree, I think it's a fairly direct answer to the question asked.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like pseudocode to me. This is common on exams. Be sure to recognize the difference between pseucode and java code. In Java, methods require parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it was pseudocode. they do that to facilitate the exercise code

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.print(k);
```

I suggest at least trying to google or read a basic guide to Java before asking these kinds of questions.

Comment: This answer should be a comment

Comment: I think our answers are as proper an answer as the question is a question.

Comment: I have been programming for a good 5 years, but I took a test, and they counted the question with that line in it CORRECT. Clearly something is going on here if that line is NOT right, and produces an error.

Answer (score -1):

In java *code* you can't use just the word `print` to print a variable as it is not recognized by java. You have to use the `System.out.print` or something of that nature for output.

Comment: print is **not** a keyword

Comment: @Aubin keyword was the wrong choice of word there.